# Implicit type conversions to integers in Postgres fail after upgrading JDBC driver

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

My application currently uses the Postgres 8.2 JDBC driver (with Postgres 8.2 database), but we are upgrading to Java 7 and the JDBC 4 driver, which is currently the 9.2-1002 release. The ultimate configuration will be the JDBC 9.2 driver with Postgres 8.2 database.

There is an exception being thrown in one of our trigger functions, and it only occurs when running with the 9.2 driver. This is an `ON UPDATE` trigger on another table. The trigger effectively does:

```
DECLARE
    mytime bigint;
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO mytime EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM current_timestamp(3))*1000;
    UPDATE resource SET lastmodified=mytime WHERE id=NEW.resource_id;
END
```

The `resource.lastmodified` column is defined as type BIGINT.

The SQL error that occurs is:

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "1355248911435.9998"
    Where: PL/pgSQL function "f_modify_resource" line 4 at SQL statement;
```

Obviously the error is in the `SELECT INTO` line; there should be a cast to BIGINT here. However, I'm wondering why the statement succeeds with the 8.2 JDBC driver, but fails with the 9.2 driver when nothing else has changed? Since the trigger code runs inside the database, shouldn't this all be transparent to the JDBC driver? I thought that PostgreSQL would continue to do an implicit cast here, but it seems to have stopped.

I've tried setting `compatible=8.2` on the JDBC connection URL with no effect also.

**Edit**
Here's the output in the statement log when running with the 9.2-1002.jdbc4 driver (and I can confirm that this occurs at least as far back as the 9.0 driver, possibly earlier):

```
STATEMENT:  UPDATE message SET hastext='true' WHERE rid='2-1355323570239' AND mid='1-1355329102968'
ERROR:  22P02: invalid input syntax for integer: "1355329102985.0002"
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "f_modify_resource" line 4 at SQL statement
LOCATION:  scanint8, int8.c:137
```

The `f_modify_resource` function is run by an `ON UPDATE` trigger on the `message` table, and its body is exactly as given above. Line 4 corresponds to the `SELECT INTO` statement. I can confirm that the `EXTRACT(EPOCH...)` does indeed return a `double precision`, and it should indeed.

With the 8.2 (jdbc4 and jdbc3) driver, this error does not occur, and statements process correctly.

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.2 is no longer supported (and is really, really old). You should really upgrade as soon as possible. You will get problems with implicit typecasting if you do, but the sooner you deal with it the better.

Comment: That's on the roadmap, but unfortunately not immediately in scope.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the only thing that changes is the JDBC driver? Please enable `log_statement = 'all'` in `postgresql.conf` and then run your test with the 8.2 and 9.2 drivers. Post the logs.

Comment: Also, are you certain that's the right trigger and that both the 9.2 and 8.2 tests are on the exact same database? And the trigger source is exactly as shown? I simply don't see how you can get a floating point result from `EXTRACT (epoch FROM ...)`.

Comment: The tests are being run on exactly the same machine, same Postgres database, same software. I stop it, swap the driver JAR, and restart it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if the JDBC driver is setting *extra_float_digits*.  The release notes say that as of 8.3-dev602 it is set to '2' upon connection whereas it normally defaults to zero.  I can't reproduce your behavior (all I have is 9.1 and 9.2 to test with).  However, I can do this:

```
postgres=# set extra_float_digits = 2;
SET
postgres=# select extract(epoch from current_timestamp(3));
     date_part      
--------------------
 1355346251.7550001
(1 row)

postgres=# select extract(epoch from current_timestamp(3));
     date_part      
--------------------
 1355346253.1619999
(1 row)
```

I can't get this to fail when multiplying by 1000 and assigning to a BIGINT, but that may be something that is 8.2-specific, so you'll have to test by using the 9.2 driver and explicitly running the statement SET extra_float_digits = 0 after you finish connecting, but before running the query that's failing.

Comment: Could be. The problem is only intermittent because the issue is with floating point precision. I managed to get a result of `1355347361873.0002` with `extra_float_digits=2`

Comment: I've ended up fixing the issue by adding an explicit cast to the function, but this looks like the prime candidate for why the issue happened in the first place. Thank-you!